# ios 5 prototype cells and VoiceOver issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I am having a problem when trying to load a prototype cell when Voiceover is on. The app crashes and I get the errors

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:]

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

This only happens when VoiceOver is on, otherwise the app runs fine. Any help?

Comment: If anyone else is having problems with this issue, I filed a bug with apple about this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem! I today started adding accessibility hints and stuff to my app. That really sucks. Could you add the radar id here so I / we can duplicate the bug. I still get that bug in 5.1 beta 2!

Comment: @ChristianBeer found your bug in Open Radar and dup'ed it. (rdar://10763569) Thanks.

Comment: This really sucks, anyone find any work arounds?

Comment: Still having the same issue when enabling VoiceOver in iOS 6.0.1, pretty infuriating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got this right by chance, but this worked out for me. In the `UITableViewDataSource`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [...]

    UITableViewCell *standardCell;
    if (UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()) {
        standardCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VO Cell"];
    } else {
        standardCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Regular Cell"];
    }

    //Configure the cell
    [...]

    return standardCell;

}
```

I believe it is the case that iOS caches Cells without the accessibility properties if VoiceOver is turned off for performance reasons. So the default Identifier you use may be related to a cached Cell that does not have these properties. When VoiceOver is turned on and iOS tries to dequeue these Cells, it does not find the properties in there and breaks. By having different Identifiers, you force iOS to cache new Cells when VO is on.

Again, **this is only an assumption I'm making**, but the case is that I do not get this issue when I dequeue Cells this way. However, if you do dequeue them the way I mentioned, you'd have to watch out for an error that may come along:

If you are dequeuing Cells whose Identifiers are set in a .xib file or in a Storyboard, like in the image below, you would then have to set another Prototype Cell with the VO Reuse Identifier.
[image: Reuse Identifier set in Interface Builder]